# Регулярные выражения и двойные кавычки в Visual Studio

Tags: регулярные-выражения, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

Задача: необходимо заменить все строки, имеющие двойные кавычки. Покажу на примере.
Есть следующая строка

```
Connection.Reader["FIELDNAME"].ToString()
```

Необходимо заменить такую строку на

```
Connection.Reader["FIELDNAME"]
```

При этом, часть строки FIELDNAME содержит разные значения. То бишь, могут быть разные варианты:

```
Connection.Reader["RegNr"].ToString(), Connection.Reader["ClientName"].ToString(), Connection.Reader["ClientAge"].ToString()
```

Как лучше всего решить данную задачу?

Comment: Какие-нибудь расширения к Студии установлены? Например, можно использовать Roslynator. Он найдёт все избыточные (redundant) вызовы методов. И можно будет парой кликов мышки удалить их все.

Comment: В данном случае, вызов метода не избыточен. Поэтому, таким способ вряд ли выйдет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Шаблон поиска

```
(Connection\.Reader\["\w+"\])\.ToString\(\)
```

`\w` - эквивалентно [a-zA-Z0-9_]
`+` - квантификатор, указывающий 1 и более совпадение

Заменяем на `$1`

---

Пример: [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/bsN1oN/1)